# pymongo upgrade to 3.0.3 causes this statement to fail

Tags: pymongo

This statement on pymongo version 2.7.2 works just fine:

```
allFieldsArray = list(fields.find({"persist": "True"}, fields={'name': 1, 'list_name': 1, '_id': 0}))
```

When I upgraded to 3.0.3, I get this:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful, feel free to upvote and/or accept them ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `projection` instead of `fields`.

```
allFieldsArray = list(fields.find(
         {"persist": "True"},
         projection={'name': 1, 'list_name': 1, '_id': 0}))
```

See the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find).